# How to convert hex to string in Perl

Tags: perl, unicode, hex

I am using Perl, and I got a string:

> agn\u00e8s b

How can I convert it to

> agnès b

?

I have tried to use the below code.

```
my $hex = "agn\u00e8s b";
$hex =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C",hex($1))/eg;
print "$hex\n";
```

But it failed and displayed some strange character. What is more, I need to display Chinese words as well. For example,

> \u9eb5\u5305

How do I it convert to the following?

> 麵包

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my $s = "agn\\u00e8s b";
$s =~ s/\\u(....)/chr(hex($1))/eg;
print "$s\n";
```

Don't forget to encode your output

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

Comment: If the above code is included in a file with the last line at the top followed by three lines, then it produced the output: agn00e8s b. Since you asked to encode the output, so, is anything amiss in the file?

Comment: @Neeraj Tuteja, That's because the OP's input (which I blindly copied) is incorrect. Fixed. Sorry, I didn't notice your comment before now.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

> $hex =~ s/(\u[a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/encode('utf-8', chr(hex($1)))/eg;

Comment: That's a completely inappropriate place to do the encoding. If you encode that character, you would have to encode the other characters too, but you're only encoding some of the characters!

Comment: @ikegami please enlighten us by providing test cases to prove your point.